# preparing online test in php using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to create a test pattern in PHP using MySQL database.Here i want to fetch questions form database and display those in my html pages. Now i want to create a division with next button and when user clicks it should display the next question that fetched from database in the same division dynamically. i guess it can be achieved through jQquery or javascript but unable to get the logic.

can anyone help.

thanks in advance.

here is a sample code that i have tried to display multiple divisions with javascript.

this is my database structure,

fields : qid,question,opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4

this is php code for fetching data form database.

```
<?php
$result=executeQuery("select * from quest");

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

//echo $row['qid'];echo "<br/>";
    echo $row['question']; echo "<br/>";
    ?>

<input type="radio" name="a1" value="'<?php echo $row['opt1']; ?>'" ><?php echo $row['opt1'];  echo "<br/>"; ?>
<input type="radio" name="a1" value="'<?php echo $row['opt2']; ?>'" ><?php echo $row['opt2']; echo "<br/>";?>
<input type="radio" name="a1" value="'<?php echo $row['opt3']; ?>'" ><?php echo $row['opt3']; echo "<br/>";?>
<input type="radio" name="a1" value="'<?php echo $row['opt4']; ?>'" ><?php echo $row['opt4']; echo "<br/>";?> 



            <?php
}
}

?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

now this fetches all the rows at a time and displays it.

this is javascript

```
var x=1;
function myfunc(){

    document.getElementById(x).style.display="block" ;
    x++;

}
```

when i click on button every time,respected division is displayed, but i want to display all data within one common division when each time the button is clicked.

Comment: every time you shud fetch from database on click of next??

Comment: eiher fetch data everytime or fetch it once ,store it in array then display it at every click.

Comment: I think you can achieve this using PHP only. It looks like a pagination with one set of data per page. But this is also achievable using Javascript. I hope you can give out more information, like MySQL database/table structure, etc. so we could help you out.

Comment: can you suggest any site or reference to this pagination if you know any..?

Comment: you need to use ajax if you want to do this without refresh, if you are ok with refresh, as suggested by @LoganWayne, use pagination with limit as 1

Comment: it is like question and answer with four options.each option is displayed with a radio button. user will select an answer and click next button which should display next question.

Comment: Well, how about your table structure? Where you fetch the questions and answers?

Comment: shall i edit my edit my post and repost it, so that you can have clear idea of what am i doing..?

Comment: @SagarPawar Sure. That would be better. And it is normal to do so.

Comment: @Logan Wayne , i have edited my post. you can ckeck it now

Comment: @SagarPawar - I saw it. I'm still typing my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91169/discussion-between-sagar-pawar-and-logan-wayne).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to reload a page when clicking the next button, we can use a Javascript library called [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

I would also suggest that you use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) rather than using the [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*` API.

Lets start first by re-establishing your `mysql_*` and turn it to `mysqli_*`:

```
/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */
$con = new mysqli("Host", "username", "password", "database"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA INSIDE */

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT qid, question, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4 FROM quest ORDER BY qid LIMIT 1")){
  $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
  $stmt->bind_result($qid, $question, $opt1, $opt2, $opt3, $opt4); /* BIND THE RESULT TO THESE VARIABLES */
  $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULT */
  $stmt->close();
} /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */
```

After we get the data, we can now put it inside your form.

```
  <h1 id="question"><?php echo $question; ?></h1>

  <input type="hidden" id="qid" value="<?php echo $qid; ?>">
  <input type="radio" name="a1" id="op1" value="<?php echo $opt1; ?>"><span id="op1text"><?php echo $opt1; ?></span><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="a1" id="op2" value="<?php echo $opt2; ?>"><span id="op2text"><?php echo $opt2; ?></span><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="a1" id="op3" value="<?php echo $opt3; ?>"><span id="op3text"><?php echo $opt3; ?></span><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="a1" id="op4" value="<?php echo $opt4; ?>"><span id="op4text"><?php echo $opt4; ?></span><br/>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Next"> <!-- THIS SERVES AS THE SUBMIT AND NEXT BUTTON -->
```

Before you proceed, download the library [here](https://jquery.com/download).

Now, we can create a script that will take the answer and go to the next question. We will submit the answer of the user to the database using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <!-- REPLACE NECESSARY JQUERY FILE DEPENDING ON THE VERSION YOU HAVE DOWNLOADED -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){ /* WHEN SUBMIT IS CLICKED */
      var qid = $("#qid").val(); /* GET THE question id */
      var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='a1']:checked");
      if (selected.length > 0) { /* CHECK THE SELECTED RADIO BUTTON */
        answer = selected.val();
      }
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", /* THE METHOD WE WILL BE USING TO PASS THE DATA */
        url: "action.php", /* THIS IS WHERE THE DATA WILL GO */
        data: {"questionid" : qid, "answer" : answer}, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING */
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(result){ /* WHEN IT IS SUCCESSFUL */
          /* THIS WILL REPLACE THE DATA IN OUR QUESTION PAGE */
          $("#qid").val(result.questionid);
          $("#question").html(result.question);
          $("#op1").val(result.op1);
          $("#op2").val(result.op2);
          $("#op3").val(result.op3);
          $("#op4").val(result.op4);
          $("#op1text").html(result.op1);
          $("#op2text").html(result.op2);
          $("#op3text").html(result.op3);
          $("#op4text").html(result.op4);
        }
      }); /* END OF AJAX */
    });
  });
</script>
```

Then, we can create the `action.php` which takes the data/answer from the question page.

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST["questionid"])){

    /* INCLUDE OUR NEW ESTABLISHED CONNECTION HERE */

    /* PUT HERE YOUR INSERT QUERY WHICH STORES THE USER'S ANSWERS */

    /* THEN FETCH THE NEXT QUESTION */
    if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT qid, question, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4 FROM quest WHERE qid > ? ORDER BY qid LIMIT 1")){
      $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["questionid"]);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($qid, $question, $opt1, $opt2, $opt3, $opt4);
      $stmt->fetch();
      $stmt->close();
    } /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */

    /* THIS SET OF DATA WILL REPLACE THE DATA IN OUR CURRENT QUESTION PAGE */
    echo json_encode(array("questionid" => $qid, "question" => $question, "op1" => $opt1, "op2" => $opt2, "op3" => $opt3, "op4", => op4));

  } /* END OF ISSET */

?>
```

Comment: it displays only one question and question doesn't change when i check anyone option and then click next.

Comment: @SagarPawar - what do you get? Errors? Hit "F12" if you are using Chrome as your browser to see the console for errors.

Answer (score -1):

if you dont want to implement with ajax. Then list all questions and use jQuery to display single div. Use 'click' functions on next button to display the next questions.

If you are going by this method, try the following instruction. Hope It will be simple for you.

Display all the questions and answers.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
<li class="test " id="qid_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >
<?php echo $row['question']; /* here display the stuff */ ?></li>
<?php }
```

Create "prev" and "next" buttons.

```
<span class="prev_q">Prev</span>      
<span class="next_q">Next</span>
```

Add this css( to make first question as active )

```
li.test { display:none; }
li.activequestion{ display:block;background:#cccccc; color:#c40001; }
```

Add the script to make prev, next buttons working

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('li.test:first').addClass('activequestion');

jQuery('.next_q').click(function(){
var nonext=jQuery('.test:last').hasClass('activequestion');
if(nonext)
{ alert("no next available"); return false; }
var currentdiv=jQuery('.activequestion').attr('id');
jQuery('.test.activequestion').next().addClass('activequestion');
jQuery('#'+currentdiv).removeClass('activequestion');
});

jQuery('.prev_q').click(function(){
var noprevious=jQuery('.test:first').hasClass('activequestion');
if(noprevious)
{ alert("no previous available"); return false; }
var currentdiv=jQuery('.activequestion').attr('id');
jQuery('.test.activequestion').prev().addClass('activequestion');
jQuery('#'+currentdiv).removeClass('activequestion');
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: add this thing in comment it is not a solutions for the question